# How to add an object to an array using redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I want to add an object to an array reducer

This is the object am trying to add

```
 const id = 1;
 const type = 'deposit';

      dispatch(addTransaction({id, type}))
```

This is my reducer

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  transactions: [],
};

const transactionSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'transaction',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addTransaction: (state, action) => {
     state.transactions = [...state.transactions, action.payload];
},
  },
});

const { actions, reducer } = transactionSlice;

export const {
  addTransaction,
} = actions;

export default reducer;
```

Anytime I dispatch the object data, It updates the previous data, instead adding a new object in my transaction array.

Answer (score 1):

Any of these two options should work:

Returning the updated state

```
const transactionSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'transaction',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addTransaction: (state, action) => {
     return [...state.transactions, action.payload];
    },
  },
});
```

Or for future scalability, make your initial state to be an object and add a key for your transactions, in this case `items`

```
const initialState = {
  transactions: {
    items: [],
  },
};

const transactionSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'transaction',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addTransaction: (state, action) => {
     transactions.items = [...state.transactions.items, action.payload];
   },
  },
});
```

With this object approach you can take advantage of Immer and get rid of having to spread the state just pushing the incoming `payload`

```
const transactionSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'transaction',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addTransaction: (state, action) => {
     transactions.items.push(action.payload);
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

change

```
const initialState = {
  transactions: {
    items: [],
  },
};
```

to

```
const initialState = {
  transactions:[]
};

{ state.transactions: [...transactions, action.transaction] };
```

or keep initial state but change reducer to:

```
state.transactions.items = [...state.transactions.items, action.payload];
```

and according to redux toolkit [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start) there is no `return` in reducer

Comment: Kindly check my slice, I updated it. But now am getting  state.transaction is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not copying the transactions state before adding the new object to it.
so do this instead:

```
reducers: {
    addTransaction: (state, action) => {
    state.transactions = [...state.transactions, action.payload];
    }
```

this way you copy all objects inside transactions array to a new array, plus the new object you want to add.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but am getting this error -> state.transaction is not iterable

Comment: You are getting this error because most probably you are using the spread operator on an object inside the array. Make sure transactions inside the initial state is an array and that you are spreading it inside an array as well in the reducer